# Is a premeasure $\mu$ on a semiring $\mathcal{P}$ is $\sigma$-subadditive? (Countable additivity $\Rightarrow$ Countable subadditivity)?

Tags: measure-theory

R.T.P: For a sequence $(A_n)$ in $\mathcal{P}$ and $A\in\mathcal{P}$ which satisfies $A\subseteq\bigcup _n A_n $ $\Rightarrow$ $\mu(A)\leq \sum^\infty _{n=1}\mu (A_n)$

I am aware of the construction $\overline{A}_n =A_n/\bigcup^{n-1}_{i=1}A_i$ which produces a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathcal{P}$ and that furthermore $\bigcup_n A_n=\bigcup_n\overline{A}_n$ which means

$$\mu(\bigcup_n A_n )=\mu(\bigcup_n \overline{A}_n) =\sum _n \mu (\overline{A}_n)\leq \sum _n \mu (A_n)$$

The last inequality leading from the monotonicity of the premeasure and the fact that $\overline{A}_n\subseteq A_n, \forall n$

All that remains is to show that $\mu(A)\leq\mu(\bigcup_n \overline{A}_n)$ as that would be the last remaining piece of the puzzle.

My question is, how do I so?

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\subseteq \bigcup_n A_n =\bigcup \overline{A}_n $ then $A=A\cap\bigcup\overline{A}_n=\bigcup(A\cap \overline{A}_n) \Rightarrow \mu(A)=\sum_n\mu(A\cap \overline{A}_n)$ by $\sigma$-additvity of $\mu$.

Since $A\cap\overline{A}_n \subseteq \overline{A}_n$ then by monotinicity of $\mu$, $\mu(A\cap\overline{A}_n)\leq\mu(\overline{A}_n), \forall n$

Thus,$$\mu(A)=\sum_n\mu(A\cap \overline{A}_n)\leq\sum_n\mu(\overline{A}_n)=\sum_n(A_n/\bigcup^{n-1}_{i=1} A_n)\leq\sum_n\mu (A_n)$$

Again, by monotinicity of $\mu$